# using combine_first on dataframe with repeated dates as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes containing meteorological data for different dates at different locations within the same dataframe, here's a simpler version of my data which reproduces the issue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(10, 4)), columns=(['Temp', 'Precip', 'Wind', 'Pressure']))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(10, 4)), columns=(['Temp', 'Precip', 'Wind', 'Pressure']))

df['Location'] =[2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
df1['Location'] =[2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
```

These are indexed by the 18th and 19th of May 2020 for df, and the 19th and 20th of May for df1 like so:

```
df.index = ["2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00"]
df1.index = ["2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00"]

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
```

The way the dataframes are structured means each `Location` point has 2 days of data in each dataframe. The 18th and 19th in df, and the 19th and 20th in df1. The look like this:

[image] [image]

I want to combine these two dataframes into df3 where I have values for the 18th, 19th and 20th for each location point, where 18th comes from df, and 19th and 20th comes from df1. i.e. df1 overwrites df for each location on the same date, then appends the data for all following dates, to produce something that looks like this:

[image]

In reality I have hundreds of locations over many days, so this will need to work based on the index (I think).

I have tried the `pd.combine_first` method like so:

```
df.combine_first(df1)
```

but (because of the repeated dates in the index) this produces a dataframe with many more cells than I want - there should be 15 in total and there are many more.

[image]

I think this is due to the index because when I tried an example with simpler dates for just one location it works fine - but I can't figure out how to do it on my data which has multiple locations within the same dataframe. I'd really appreciate some help!

**EDIT:** the answer marked below does solve this issue, but now when I want to add new data which doesn't match the index length like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(10, 4)), columns=(['Temp', 'Precip', 'Wind', 'Pressure']))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=(11, 4)), columns=(['Temp', 'Precip', 'Wind', 'Pressure']))

df['Location'] =[2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]
df1['Location'] =[1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]

df.index = ["2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00","2020-05-18 12:00:00","2020-05-19 12:00:00"]
df1.index = ["2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00", "2020-05-20 12:00:00", "2020-05-19 12:00:00"]

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)

df1
```

[image]

So I now have another location with the value 1, I want to add this location to df along with updating the values with those of df1. When I use the following code:

```
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
df1 = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)

df = df.combine_first(df1).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df)
```

[image]

It updates df with the values from df2, but it removes the new location. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem with duplicates, so `combine_first` create default outer join. Solution is add helper level in `MultiIndex` for unique index values and last sorting with remove helper level:

```
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
df1 = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
 
df = df.combine_first(df1).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df)
                     Temp  Precip  Wind  Pressure  Location
2020-05-18 12:00:00  24.0     3.0   5.0      28.0       2.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00   8.0    21.0   2.0       6.0       2.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00  10.0    12.0   4.0      15.0       2.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00  25.0     4.0   6.0      14.0       3.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00  19.0     8.0  13.0      14.0       3.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00   5.0     5.0  13.0       1.0       3.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00   6.0    27.0  16.0      15.0       4.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00  24.0     3.0  24.0      25.0       4.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00  13.0     5.0  28.0      22.0       4.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00  18.0    26.0  13.0      23.0       5.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00  13.0    27.0  15.0      16.0       5.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00  25.0    11.0   6.0      21.0       5.0
2020-05-18 12:00:00  23.0    21.0   3.0      22.0       6.0
2020-05-19 12:00:00   6.0    12.0  10.0       2.0       6.0
2020-05-20 12:00:00   2.0    12.0  12.0      14.0       6.0
```

Comment: This works and solves the problem for the example above and my more complex data, I have therefore marked it as the answer - thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry to disturb you - I am having a problem adding new data when using this method as the new locations have less data then the existing ones, I have edited the question above to illustrate the new issue and would be v grateful if you could look at it if you get the chance!

Answer (score 2):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df,df1]).reset_index()
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset=["index","Location"], keep="last")
df3 = df3.set_index("index").sort_index().sort_values(by="Location")

In [29]: df3
Out[29]: 
             

                     Temp  Precip  Wind  Pressure  Location
index                                                      
2020-05-18 12:00:00     9      13    17        27         2
2020-05-19 12:00:00    23      27    22         0         2
2020-05-20 12:00:00    21      22     0         5         2
2020-05-18 12:00:00    22      27    19        13         3
2020-05-19 12:00:00     4      29    21         0         3
2020-05-20 12:00:00    12      28    11        25         3
2020-05-18 12:00:00    29       8    21        20         4
2020-05-19 12:00:00    10       3    15        25         4
2020-05-20 12:00:00    23       2    14         5         4
2020-05-18 12:00:00    11      19    17        17         5
2020-05-19 12:00:00    13       1    12         7         5
2020-05-20 12:00:00     4      18    25        19         5
2020-05-18 12:00:00     3      21    16        18         6
2020-05-19 12:00:00    16      12    11        12         6
2020-05-20 12:00:00    27      19    13        19         6
    
In [30]: df3.shape
Out[30]: (15, 5)
```

Comment: just modify `df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset=["index","Location"], keep="last").set_index("index").sort_index().sort_values(['Location'])` to have the expected output

Comment: Thank you - this works for my example - but when I use it on my actual data I get the error `
KeyError: Index(['index'], dtype='object')` - I'm not sure why and am looking into it.

Comment: It means that the dataframe does not have a "index" column. on which line do you get the error ?

Comment: When I run this `df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(subset=["index","FarmID"], keep="last")` I get the error

Comment: If you have the `.reset_index` before, you should have an "index" column. Can you check your `df3` before using `.drop_duplicates` ?

Comment: Yes I checked it and it has an index of 0-1099 (dataset has 1100 rows) - I am unsure why it is not working

Comment: are you sure you have BOTH an index and an index column. if you type `df3.columns` you should see "index" in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220097/discussion-between-pad-and-amh).